# Microsoft Security login box when downloading Word document

Tags: windows, security, ms-word, download, popup

I've looked around online for this but can't seem to find an answer anywhere so hopefully someone can help.

I'm getting a "Windows Security" popup appearing on a site I've created (and so are others which is who I need to fix it for rather than myself) when trying to download a word document or excel file. PDFs seem fine.

An example page is http://www.christletonhigh.co.uk/school_information/uniform.php if you click to download the “Uniform Prices & Order Form” in the bottom right.

There’s no SSL on the site and the error only comes up on IE (I'm using IE9 on Windows 7 which I've seen others mentioning online as their setup with this happeneding) and doesn’t seem to effect all files so it’s a bit confusing. Clicking cancel on the popup causes the document to open anyway.

Anyone have any ideas please? The client tells me that the documents causing the problems have never been password protected.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the dialogue box in question and pop a reply to me below? This may not be a programming related question but without a screenshot I can't migrate this somewhere you might get a better set of eyes. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kev, no problem if you take a look here please: www.uqwebdesign.com/screenshot.png

Comment: Have you found the solution? Because I am facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the reference, here's the detailed explanation why this happens: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105

Solution mentioned by Anshuman should work: create script that adds "Content-Disposition" header with "attachment" value. For example: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.doc"`. This will force all the content (including PDF, images, etc.) to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

- Security settings aside, other browsers seem to handle this more gracefully than IE9. Chrome, for example, seems to handle the download of the document with ease, and not result in a Windows Security dialog prompting for credentials to their network...
- The users can disabled the 'protected view' settings from Word options | Trust Center, and the document will open with no dialog (probably not desirable to instruct them to do this)

I suppose this is the risk one takes when having users download content which require other applications to handle. a PDF would be better (hence the "P" for "Portable"), so if they can use PDF, that would be my first advice.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you give the direct URL path of the file and let the browser handle the file. To resolve this create a php script that explicitly downloads the file. Hope this helps :)